# Cygwin creates files with special (shared) icons on windows

Tags: windows, files, cygwin

I use cygwin to transfer files between linux and windows machines. Everytime I transfer a file to a windows machine it adds an extra shared user icon on the file's or folder's icon itself. This also happens if I create a file from cygwin on windows using pretty much any command: echo, vim, nano, cat.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8QMj.png) is what the cygwin-created folders (and files) look like. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cylz7.png) is what a normal folder (or file) looks like.

I'm thinking it has to do with permission, because I'd have to chmod it everytime if I want other applications to access the files or folders on windows.

How can I tell cygwin to create regular ol' files just like a user or any program would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew! I finally solved it.

If anyone else is having this trouble on Cygwin 1.7* do the following:

```
 vim /etc/fstab
```

or open `/etc/fstab` in your favorite editor... and add this line to it:

```
 none   /cygdrive cygdrive posix=0,noacl 0 0
```

Then restart cygwin. The share icon from cygwin created files and folders should now be removed.